# WPF Trigger Button CanExecute outside ItemsControl from within ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to extend the app from a WPF MVVM tutorial as an exercise. I've found no solution on the net for this specific problem I'm facing here.

I have a ViewModel with an ObservableCollection called "StudentsToAdd". This collection is bound to an ItemsControl. Outside the ItemsControl I have a Button with a binding to the "AddCommand" command in the ViewModel. The relevant extract form my XAML looks as follows:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="+" Command="{Binding AddToAddListCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3,0,3,0" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
        <Button Content="-" Command="{Binding RemoveFromAddListCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,5,0" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="AddList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StudentsToAdd}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Margin="0 5 3 5">
                        <TextBox.InputBindings>
                            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ElementName=AddList, Path=DataContext.AddCommand}" Key="Return"/>
                        </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Margin="0 5 3 5">
                        <TextBox.InputBindings>
                            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ElementName=AddList, Path=DataContext.AddCommand}" Key="Return"/>
                        </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The + and - buttons will add or remove students from the StudentsToAdd collection. The "AddCommand" moves all entries from StudentsToAdd to another collection called "Students" when executed.

Now what I can't get to work is this: whenever a Student in StudentsToAdd is modified (after any keystroke: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`). I want the Add Button to evaluate the CanExecute of AddCommand in the ViewModel so its IsEnabled property is automatically set accordingly. The command methods in the ViewModel currently look as follows:

```
private void OnAdd()
{
    foreach (Student s in StudentsToAdd)
    {
        Students.Add(s);
    }
    StudentsToAdd.Clear();
    StudentsToAdd.Add(new Student { FirstName = string.Empty, LastName = string.Empty });
}

private bool CanAdd()
{
    if (StudentsToAdd != null && StudentsToAdd.Count > 0)
    {
        return StudentsToAdd.All(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.LastName));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve this without coupling parts of the MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody know how I can achieve this without coupling parts of the MVVM?

There's not much context in your question. But, it seems that you are asking how to accomplish this entirely within the view model/model layer, without involving the view layer. At least, that's what you *should* be asking.

If so, it should be relatively simple, assuming the code you didn't show is written reasonably. That is, since your `CanAdd()` method depends on property values of the `Student` objects, you'll need to subscribe to the `Student.PropertyChanged` event, and raise the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event any time any of the `Student` objects' `PropertyChanged` event is raised.

For what it's worth, I would also encapsulate the "can be added" logic in the `Student` class, rather than the `ViewModel` class. Expose that state as a single property that the `ViewModel` class can check. This will address a couple of things:

1. Your `Student` class seems like the more logical place to put code that determines whether the class is ready to be added to a list of `Students`, and
2. The `ViewModel` class can check to make sure it's that property that is changing, so it doesn't bother to go to all the work to check all the other `Student` objects every time any `Student` property changes, *and* each `Student` object will effectively be caching the "can be added" value, so that that work to check all the other `Student` objects is a simple property retrieval, instead of having to re-evaluate the state every single time.

I assume you already understand how to raise the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event, but if not, here are a couple of posts that should help you with that:

[CanExecuteChanged event of ICommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6425923)
[ICommand CanExecuteChanged not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19657463)

(You'll see that there are two basic strategies: implement something in the `ICommand` object that will explicitly raise the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event, or call `InputManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to force the Input Manager to call all the `CanExecute()` methods it knows about. IMHO, the latter is a pretty heavy-weight and less-desirable approach, hence my suggestion to use the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event.)

Comment: Why haven't I thought of this? It's quite obvious and works beautifully. The only downside is the constant hooking and unhooking of the Student.PropertyChanged event within the ViewModel whenever students are added or removed from the StudentsToAdd collection.